# Connection Timeout between Ansible and Windows Server

Tags: networking, ssl, windows-server-2016, ansible, winrm

I'm starting my studies with Ansible and wanted to apply it to a real situation of my work.
I am implementing Ansible from Ubuntu to manage a Windows Nano Server 2016. I'm configuring to use a certificate mapped to a user account.
I based this tutorial here https://adamtheautomator.com/winrm-https-ansible/

---

### The Error

I tested the connection using the win_ping module and I received this output:

```
**ansible windows -vvvv -i hosts -m win_ping**

NanoServer | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for 
    *debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
    debug1: Control socket \"/home/woliveira/.ansible/cp/6df2d837bc\" does not exist
    debug2: resolving \"nanoserver\" port 5986
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to nanoserver [10.11.39.250] port 5986.
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug3: timeout: 25000 ms remain after connect
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
    **Connection timed out during banner exchange",
    "unreachable": true**
}
```

Next, I tried to increase the timeout in the ansible config file and I receive a Connection reset by peer.

```
NanoServer | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
        debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
        debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
        debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for 
        *debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
        debug1: Control socket \"/home/woliveira/.ansible/cp/6df2d837bc\" does not exist
        debug2: resolving \"nanoserver\" port 5986
        debug2: ssh_connect_direct
        debug1: Connecting to nanoserver [10.11.39.250] port 5986.
        debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
        debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
        debug1: Connection established.
        debug3: timeout: 3600000 ms remain after connect
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
        debug1: identity file /home/woliveira/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
        debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
        kex_exchange_identification: read: **Connection reset by peer",
        "unreachable": true**
    }
```

### The Environment Setup.

The **Ansible 2.9.6**  is installed in a  **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS** VM

My windows server is the following:
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

Both VMs have Static Ip and are not in a domain. I follow this tutorial:
https://vnuggets.com/2019/08/08/ansible-certificate-authentication-to-windows/

I created a Windows local user called ansibleoperator and I added this user in Local Admi Group.
This is my Ansible hosts file:

```
[windows]
NanoServer

[windows:vars]
ansible_user=ansibleoperator
ansible_password=*********
ansble_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_cert_pem=/home/woliveira/cert.pem
ansible_winrm_cert_key_pem=/home/woliveira/cert_key.pem
ansible_port=5986
ansible_winrm_scheme=https
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

The windows firewall is disabled
TrustedHosts is configured for any host (vallue=*)

### What I've checked

If Another Windows host is able to connect using winrm:
PS C:> Test-WSMan -ComputerName "NanoServer" -UseSSL

```
wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```

From the Linux side I'm able to use Netcat to test the connection in the 5986 port using the following command:

```
 nc -z -w1 NanoServer 5986;echo $?
```

The output is 0 (Command succeded)

I'm already tried to connect from other Windows, but this time using pywinrm script since is the same lib that Ansible use.
I run this Script:

```
import winrm

cert_pem = 'C:/Users/woliveira.adm/Desktop/CertificadoAnsible/cert.pem'
cert_key_pem = 'C:/Users/woliveira.adm/Desktop/CertificadoAnsible/cert_key.pem'


session = winrm.Session('NanoServer:5986', auth=('ansibleoperator', '********'),
                        transport='certificate',
                        cert_pem=cert_pem, 
                        cert_key_pem=cert_key_pem,
                        server_cert_validation='ignore',
                        )
session.run_cmd('ipconfig')
```

And receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-b902c730fb9c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/woliveira.adm/Desktop/testewinrm.py', wdir='C:/Users/woliveira.adm/Desktop')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/woliveira.adm/Desktop/testewinrm.py", line 19, in <module>
    session.run_cmd('ipconfig')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\winrm\__init__.py", line 39, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 323, in send_message
    response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 328, in _send_message_request
    response = self.session.send(prepared_request, timeout=self.read_timeout_sec)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.11.39.250', port=5986): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
```

I don't know how I could debug this.
What could I check?

Sorry about my English. If there is something that is not clear enough, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your vars file:

```
ansble_connection=winrm
```

This should be:

```
ansible_connection=winrm
```

(there is an `i` missing).

That's why Ansible is trying to connect via SSH instead of WinRM.

Comment: Oh Man. Shame on me. I spent hours because of an I letter